# validation that allows user to select dates between a period of 12 months

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two date pickers with from date and to date now my requirement is to allow user to select dates between 12 months.Suppose if he selects 1/1/2016 as from date the to date can be any date till 1/1/2017 if it exceeds 12 months an error message should be displayed an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTime.AddMonths(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) seems to be what you need. Something like:

```
if (start.AddMonths(12) >= end) 
{
    // Valid
}
else
{
    // Not Valid
}
```

Comment: yes if user selects the from and to dates between 12 months it should accept if the selected period of from date and to date is more than 12 months it should display user to select date between the 12 month period